# setInterval(): How to stop then start itself again?

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, setinterval

In a if statement, I want the interval to clear itself and then call object function of itself again to restart the interval.

Is such thing possible?

I tried it this way, but I'm getting unexpected behavior. I can see that the log keeps on logging every 200ms. While it should have stopped since the interval was stopped and restarted and the condition wouldn't evaluate to true anymore.

```
DateTime.prototype = {
    start: function () {
        var self = this;

        sendAjaxRequest(this.timeUrl, function () {
            var previousTime = new Date().getTime();

            this.tickIntervalId = setInterval(function tick() {
                var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

                if ((currentTime - previousTime) < 0) {
                    console.log('You changed your time backwards. Restarting.');

                    self.stop(); // <-- stopping itself
                    self.start(); // <-- call to same method its running from

                    return;
                }

                self.dateElement.innerHTML = new Date();

                previousTime = currentTime;

                return tick;
            }(), 200);
        });
    },

    stop: function () {
        clearInterval(this.tickIntervalId);

        this.tickIntervalId = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your running in to some trouble with the IIFE pattern. I'd define the tick function outside the scope and reference it in the setTimeout by name not by invoking.

Comment: Maybe changing `this.tickIntervalId` to `self.tickIntervalId` is enough. `this` has many different meanings in JS' many scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the scope is wrong for the setInterval call.

Try to change

```
this.tickIntervalId = setInterval(function tick() {
```

to use self

```
self.tickIntervalId = setInterval(function tick() {
```

Comment: You mean `self`? `that` doesn't exist.